# How to use tar_make() to cache a list of files saved in a rds file?

Tags: r, caching, target

I am trying to use the `targets` package in R to cache a list of files written in a big rds file.

My code looks like that:

```
library(targets)
path <- fs::path("","Volumes","My_folder")
# Load package
library(targets)

# Comfig
tar_option_set(packages = c("readr", "tidyverse"))

list(
  tar_target(
    df_list,
    read_rds(paste0(path,
                    "/filename.rds"))
  ))

tar_make()
```

I get the error message

```
• start target df_list
✖ error target df_list
• end pipeline: 1.066 seconds
Error : unused argument (col_types = cols())
✖ Problem with the pipeline.
ℹ Show errors: tar_meta(fields = error, complete_only = TRUE)
ℹ Learn more: https://books.ropensci.org/targets/debugging.html
Error:
! problem with the pipeline.
```

Note: The code is working when using a non-list file in a rds.
I also tried with no luck:

```
list(
  tar_target(
    df_list,
    read_rds(paste0(path,
                    "/filename.rds"))[["i"]]
  ))
```

Any idea how to make it work or if it's even possible?

Comment: The error happens not in your `df_list` target, but instead in `ROI_overall_bivariate`, you should check there or share that part of the code. Also consider the Targets Manual under [External files](https://books.ropensci.org/targets/data.html#external-files) on storing external data in your cache.

Comment: @Jonathan I edited my code. I forgot changing the name of the data when I asked my question.

Comment: please see my solution below, if it solved your problem, please upvote and accept it, that would be very helpful; otherwise feel free to comment on it

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read all the data in one target, as file-paths are treated separately in targets. One has to create

1. a target for the file names in character format,
2. a dynamic target which character vector from 1. as filenames,
3. a dynamic target which reads the files and caches the content based on target 2..

I tried to provide a reproducible example:

```r
# create example files: walk(1:3, ~ write_rds(mtcars, paste0("mtcars", .x, ".rds")))

library(targets)

path <- fs::path(".")
tar_option_set(packages = c("readr", "tidyverse"))

list(
  tar_target(
    paths,
    paste0(path, c("/mtcars1.rds", "/mtcars2.rds", "/mtcars3.rds")),
  ),
  tar_target(files, paths, format = "file", pattern = map(paths)),
  tar_target(data, read_rds(files), pattern = map(files))
)
```

Comment: I am not sure that my question was clear. I have only 1 rds file "filename.rds". This file is a list which contains 4 data frames. I want to save each data frame under 1 target. Does that help?